# Should you call ReleaseStringUTFChars if GetStringUTFChars returned a copy?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

The book "Essential JNI: Java Native Interface" by Rob Gordon contains the following code example to convert a jstring to a C string:

```
const char* utf_string;
jboolean isCopy;
utf_string = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, &isCopy);
/* ... use string ... */
if (isCopy == JNI_TRUE) {
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, utf_string);
}
```

Note that it only calls `ReleaseStringUTFChars` if `isCopy` is true.

But the book [Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#5161) (alternate link: `http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#5161`) says:

> The ReleaseString-Chars call is
>   necessary whether GetStringChars has
>   set *isCopy to JNI_TRUE or JNI_FALSE.
>   ReleaseStringChars either frees the
>   copy or unpins the instance, depending
>   upon whether GetStringChars has
>   returned a copy or not.

I am correct in assuming this is a bug in Gordon's book?

Comment: where is `str` defiined?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct (you should always call ReleaseStringUTFChars).

Comment: What happen does if it will not be called ?

Comment: Memory will be leaked (the JVM will believe that you need the memory indefinitely).

Comment: Sure ! But why we don't have free allocated memory function for another data types such as : int, double . It should be RealseInt(arg,arg), ReleaseDouble(arg,arg)...or something like that ?

Comment: Int and double aren't variable-length like strings, so the data can be trivially copied to the caller.  (It's probably best to create a new question rather than continuing a conversation on a 6-year-old answer.)

Comment: Please clarify. I read that arbitrary arguments are passed as pass by mechanism method from Java to C as local reference. If yes, then it would be eventually cleaned up as soon as native method execution is done, and there wont be memory leak right?

Comment: @Vidz It's probably best to open a new question.  It's a local reference only: the JNI cannot know whether you're holding the `char *` beyond the end of the JNI method.