# Java: Invoking native method giving "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a simple native method in Java from C++, to achieve this I do the following:

1. Create a simple class as shown below:

   ```
   public class HelloNative{
      public native void printString(String str);
      static{
           System.out.println("Current Directory is: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
           System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/libhellonative.so");
       }
       public static void main(String[] args){
           System.out.println("Calling Native Libraray (libhellonative.so) method printString");
           new HelloNative().printString("Message from Java to C");
        }
   }
   ```
2. Create .h file for the native method using `javah -jni` which create the following declaration:

   `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloNative_printString(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);`
3. Implement the native function in `.cpp` file as:

   ```
   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloNative_printString(JNIEnv* jni_env, jobject java_obj, jstring msg){
       printf("inside native method\n");
       jboolean iscopy;
       const char *message = (jni_env)->GetStringUTFChars( msg, &iscopy);
       printf("%s", message);
   }
   ```
4. And finally create the `.so` file using:

   `g++ HelloNative.cpp  -o libhellonative.so -shared -Wl,-soname,libhellonative.so -static -lc -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include/linux`

But when I compile and run the .java file it's giving me Runtime Exception:

```
Current Directory is: /home/gmuhammad/Projects/test
Calling Native Libraray (libhellonative.so) method printString
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HelloNative.printString(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at HelloNative.printString(Native Method)
    at HelloNative.main(HelloNative.java:16)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got this to work.  It has nothing to do with loading the library, but with actually calling the method from that library.

I created `.java`, `.h` and `.cpp` files by copy/paste from your question and ran them (I had to add `#include <jni.h>` in the `.cpp` file) - and got exactly the same error as you did.

Then I edited the `.cpp` file to include the generated `.h` file.  Also, as *maba* indicated in his answer, you need to call `(jni_env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(msg, message);` to release the object.  My full `.cpp` file now looks like this:

```
#include "HelloNative.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloNative_printString(JNIEnv* jni_env, jobject java_obj, jstring msg){
    printf("inside native method\n");
    jboolean iscopy;
    const char *message = (jni_env)->GetStringUTFChars( msg, &iscopy);
    printf("%s", message);
    (jni_env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(msg, message);
}
```

I re-compiled the library, ran the java code - and voila! everything works. This way, it works regardless of which way you load the library, with `load` or `loadLibrary`.

Give it a try.

Comment: got it working now. :D. Thanks, but one more thing, why do I need to call (jni_env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(msg, message); as the string which is got printed is passing from the java environment. Should not it be garbage collected by jvm?

Comment: Still waiting for an answer and confused about the above question.... will be more thankful if someone can explain...

Comment: @gmuhammad Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859673/should-you-call-releasestringutfchars-if-getstringutfchars-returned-a-copy - the question itself answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to load the library slightly differently.

1. Place your `libmynative.so` into whatever directory you like.
2. Add that directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.
3. In your java code, change `System.load` call to be `System.loadLibrary("mynative")` (note the lack of full path, prefix *lib* and extension *.so*)
4. Run your java code.

Have a look here for more details: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html

Comment: tried what you suggest but I got following error:
Current Directory is: /home/gmuhammad/Projects/test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libhellonative.so in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
 at HelloNative.<clinit>(HelloNative.java:11)
Could not find the main class: HelloNative.  Program will exit.

Comment: just adding the value of the environment variable you suggested:

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/gmuhammad/Projects/test

Comment: @gmuhammad (1) Before loading the library, do `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));` and check that the directory where the library is located is included there. (2) Did you copy/paste my code?  I misnamed the library file - make sure it's correct.

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/i386:/home/gmuhammad/Projects/test:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib

   That's what I got

Comment: Why it is giving different value of java library path, when I printed using echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and totally different value when printed using System.out. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: @gmuhhamad LD_LIBRARY_PATH is your environment variable.  Internally, JVM will look for native libraries in all directories in the java.library.path variable, which among other things includes LD_LIBRARY_PATH directories

Comment: which means it should include /home/gmuhammad/Projects/test (which is LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my case), but as a matter of fact it is not printing in the System.out statement. am I right?

Comment: should I copy my .so file in one of these directory which System.out is printing? Is it necessary? Why it is not loading from current directory. I do not understand what I am missing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally OK to use the `System.load()` but you will have to be sure that your shared libraries really are where you say they should be.

```
Current Directory is: /home/gmuhammad/Projects/test
```

Your code is trying to access the shared library in that directory. Are you sure that the `libhellonative.so` is there?

Then you can also use the `System.mapLibraryName("hellonative")` to get the name of the shared library for the current platform. That makes it more platform independent. The call will give you `libhellonative.so` on linux and `hellonative.dll` on windows.

Also you must call `(jni_env)->GetReleaseUTFChars(msg, message);` to release the objects.

Comment: libraray is in my current directory, that is why I use the System.getProperty("user.dir").

Comment: adding the directory listing:

drwxr-xr-x 2 gmuhammad gmuhammad 4096 2012-08-21 19:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 gmuhammad gmuhammad 4096 2012-08-21 16:43 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 gmuhammad gmuhammad  950 2012-08-21 19:58 HelloNative.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 gmuhammad gmuhammad  351 2012-08-21 18:06 HelloNative.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 gmuhammad gmuhammad  421 2012-08-21 16:51 HelloNative.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 gmuhammad gmuhammad  485 2012-08-21 19:58 HelloNative.java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gmuhammad gmuhammad 7056 2012-08-21 18:06 libhellonative.so