# Must ReleaseStringUTFChars be called after GetStringUTFChars (when passing the char* to C function)?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I am a bit confused about the the objects which is passed to c from java? Should they be deleted inside the native jni method or they will be garbage collected when the method returns. For example:

if I have a native declaration in my java file `public native printString(String msg);` and the native method is using `const char *message = (jni_env)->GetStringUTFChars(msg, &iscopy);` to get c-style character array of string. `Shoud I call (jni_env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(msg, message);` after doing all the stuff in native method. If yes, then why it is necessary? Why not java runtime environment be doing this on the behalf of programmer? After all the string was declared and passed from java environment.

Comment: C is not Java. C does not know how to be Java. This is not about the Java or the JVM. This is about an *implementation* that is exposing it's guts to C. Thus any assumption that the Java implementations needs to "being doing this [memory management] on behalf of the programmer" is no longer a Universal Java Truth.

Comment: My point is that msg was declared inside .java file or inside the java environment. So it should be handled or garbage collected by jvm. If I am using msg for read only purpose inside the native c method, then what is the use of releasing it inside the native method.

Comment: See my first comment. It doesn't matter in which *source file/language* the object was created. It is now *just an object* in the JVM; and one that C has it's grubby little paws on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you call ReleaseStringUTFChars if GetStringUTFChars returned a copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859673/should-you-call-releasestringutfchars-if-getstringutfchars-returned-a-copy)

Comment: @KeithRandall: I also want to discuss the reasons behind ReleaseStringUTFChars function call.

Comment: @gmuhammad: the reason is discussed at that link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Get Characters function pins the characters in memory until the Release method is called. Java is unable to garbage collect or otherwise move this data until it is sure that no-one is using it.

The Java VM can not know anything about how long the memory will be used for once it leaves the Java virtual machine, therefore it requires manual notification that the memory has been finished with.

Comment: So, ReleaseStringUTFChars is just deleting the reference or pointer not the contents, and the contents are deleted by jvm when it'll be garbage collected (msg goes out of scope inside .java file). am I right?

Comment: @gmuhammad The Java file (or scope) does *not* affect object lifetime. It is the strong-reachability (or lack thereof) of an *object* that does ..

Comment: Yes, you can think of Get meaning "I have a reference to the string" and Release meaning "I don't have that reference anymore" - the GC uses that to do its job.

Comment: @TomWhittock: Thanks, I was confused about the ReleaseStringUTFChars function call, but now I am clear. Thanks for the explaining everything. :)