# How GetStringUTFChars and ReleaseStringUTFChars works?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

The [stackoverflow.com/questions/5859673](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859673) states that the `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` must be called regardless the string was copied or not. So what is the parameter `jboolean *isCopy` in the `GetStringUTFChars()` good for?

Can I release the C string when the original jstring is out of scope? For example in this pseudo code:

```
static const char *cstr;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_Run(JNIEnv *e, jobject obj, jstring s) {
    cstr = (*e)->GetStringUTFChars(e, s, 0);
}

void cfunc() {
    // Can I use and release the cstr here? How?
}
```

According to documentation I have to get a reference via `NewGlobalRef()` and release it later if I want to use java object after the JNI call finish. Is this rule valid for strings retrieved via `GetStringUTFChars()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isCopy` parameter for `GetStringUTFChars()` is only an attempt to provide a signature consistent with other similar JNI functions. In all known JVM implementations it is always invariably **`JNI_TRUE`**, because the Java strings are stored internally in an incompatible UCS-16 format.

But still, you cannot release `cstr` without knowing the context.